# Sending broadcast message through WhatsApp

Tags: android, whatsapp

I am trying to build an android app , and I reach this point that can I use (broadcast message) feature of WhatsApp in my app , by choosing a random 10 friends (or 10 phone numbers from his contacts) and send them a text message through my app ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: is that possible or not ? to share a text from my app to a 10 random numbers through whatsapp ( by using broadcast feature ) ?

Answer (score 3):

In [this](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012) link, there are instructions that explain how you can integrate WhatsApp with your app.

It seems that broadcast is not supported by the API, only "regular" message.

Comment: Exactly, you can't access any What'sApp APIs unless those exposed by them as described in the link